# jQuery Mobile Alignment Causes Double Selection when Hiding/Showing Textboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, show-hide

I have three textboxes, each with content underneath them, in a structure like so:

```
<div id="RadioText">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Response" id="Text" />
    <label>label text</label>
</div>
<div>Text related content</div>
<div id="RadioPhone">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Response" id="Phone" />
    <label>label text</label>
</div>
<div>Phone related content</div>
<div id="RadioEmail">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Response" id="Email" />
    <label>label text</label>
</div>
<div>Email related content</div>
```

On page initialization, the content divs are hidden, using `display: none`. When any checkbox is checked, the other two checkboxes disappear, and the checked box's content div is shown.

When the checked box is subsequently unchecked, its content box disappears, and nothing but the three checkboxes is displayed.

For example, if "Phone" is selected, the screen changes from this:

```
[   ] Text
[   ] Phone
[   ] E-mail
```

To this:

```
[ X ] Phone
  Phone Number: _________________
```

Notice that the Phone checkbox is now in the position of the Text checkbox, and that the same position will be occupied by the Text checkbox after the Phone checkbox is unchecked. The problem this presents is that, when the Text checkbox reappears, the change event is triggered on that checkbox, and it reads as checked, thus displaying its' content div. The physical checkbox, however, is not displayed as checked.

This is a physical thing. If I place a top margin in the Text checkbox, so that it is not reappearing exactly beneath the box being unchecked, the problem does not occur.

Here is an example of the markup for one checkbox:

```
<div id="RadioPhone">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ResponseType" id="RespondPhone" value="RP" />
    <label for="RespondPhone">Phone</label>
</div>
<div id="RespondPhoneContent" style="display:none;">
    <div style="width:56%; float:left;">
        <div class="Label">Phone Number:</div>
        <div class="Input">
            <input type="Number" class="Phone" name="Phone" id="Phone" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:25%; display:inline-block; margin-left:10px;">
        Ext:<br />
        <input type="text" name="Ext" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript for the Phone's `onchange` event. The code for other checkboxes is identical, except the names have been changed to protect the selected. These bits of code will later be put into functions to avoid redundancy, but this is how I put it together as I was experimenting:

When a checkbox is checked, it needs to hide the other two checkbox divs. When it is unchecked, it needs to hide its content block and show the other two checkboxes again.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#CabNow", function ()
{
    $("#RespondPhone").bind ("change", function (event) {
        if($("input#RespondPhone").attr ("checked"))
        {
            $("#RespondPhoneContent").show();
            $("#RadioText").hide();
            $("#RadioEmail").hide();
            $('#Phone').focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#RespondPhoneContent").hide();
            $("#RadioText").show();
            $("#RadioEmail").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what version of jQm are you using? use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.  Try to make a jsfiddle to clarify the problem.

Comment: I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 and jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: Tried using prop(), but it made no difference.

Comment: I dont recommedn using `.show()` / `.hide()` in jqm, instead us a custom class with `display: none;`. any, try changes i've made in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8u6h4/ using `.trigger("updatelayout");`. I dont know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I can create a jsfiddle if you want to access it on a phone. This code works fine on a pc - works fine on a Nexus tablet - works on a Dell XT2 touch screen. Works as described in my post on an Android phone. Waiting for an iPhone to test.

Comment: Omar - Looked at you jsfiddle. Thanks. But each checkbox has its own hidden content and functions the same as the Phone checkbox. You can see the page at http://www.slcbestcab.com/m/cabnow-m.php

Comment: Working fine on iPhone 5. As I said, add/removeClass instead of show/hide as the latter adds `display: block.;` to visible element which could mess up your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L3bUK/2/)**

I added some classes to the checkboxes content divs and container divs and also moved the content divs within the checkbox divs.  After that you can use one Change handler and respond when checked is TRUE and only when all 3 are false.

If all 3 are unchecked, all checkbox divs are shown and all content divs are hidden.
When one is checked, the siblings are hidden and the local content div is shown.

```
<div id="RadioText" class="checkDIV">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Response" id="Text" class="checkClass" />
    <label for="Text">label text</label>
    <div id="TextContent" class="contentDiv">Text related content</div>
</div>

<div id="RadioPhone" class="checkDIV">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Response" id="Phone" class="checkClass"/>
    <label for="Phone">label phone</label>
    <div id="PhoneContent" class="contentDiv">Phone related content</div>
</div>

<div id="RadioEmail" class="checkDIV">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Response" id="Email" class="checkClass"/>
    <label for="Email">label email</label>
    <div id="EmailContent" class="contentDiv">Email related content</div>
</div>

$(document).on("pageshow", "#page1", function() {   
    $(".contentDiv").hide();   
    $(".checkClass").on("change", function(){
        var IsChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
        if (IsChecked){
            $(this).parents(".checkDIV").siblings("div.checkDIV").hide();
            $(this).parents(".ui-checkbox").siblings(".contentDiv").show();
        } else {
             //if none checked reset
            if ($(".checkClass:checked").length == 0){
                $(".checkDIV").show();
                $(".contentDiv").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks great! Intelligent way of handling this. Tried it on Android and worked fine. Incorporating this code into the page and will report back.

Comment: Unfortunately, although your code is much more elegant and efficient, it did not solve the problem. It seemed to work okay on jsfiddle, though, so maybe it has to do with jQuery Mobile version. The actual page is at [link]http://www.slcbestcab.com/m/cabnow.php

Comment: Is it the 'enhanced' span that is getting checked, or the underlying input? If it is the input, try adding the CSS: input.checkClass{display: none;}.  We could also try z-index, i.e. make the visible div have the highest z-index...I have updated my fiddle with these changes and to use a hide class as suggested by Omar (also added a stopPropagation()): http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L3bUK/5/

Comment: First jsfiddle code worked well on my Android test phone, but not on actual page. Probably dofference in jqm 1.4 and 1.3.2. I believe the problem is with jqm 1.3.2 and Android 2-3. Works fine on Dell XT2 touch laptop and a Nexus 7 tablet. The problem appears to be the hidden Text checkbox comes up directly underneath the last checkbox that was unchecked. Maybe you have something there with the z-index. I'll update my code. Alternative is removing two lines that hold instructional text top of form - checked box appears there instead of over Text checkbox. Works, but don't like hiding that text.

Comment: Your latest rendition works a good majority of the time. But there are some glitches - About 50% of the time, upon first arriving on the page and selecting the Text button, the content appears and disappears. Other times, the text content may appear with the checkbox unchecked. Still, other times, the same original problem occurs.

Comment: I see you have jQuery Mobile 1.3 selected in jsfiddle. The page title said JQM 1.4, so I assumed that setting looking at my browser tab.

Comment: Just tested your code on an iPhone and a Samsung Galaxy and it works fine. Appears that I have one version of Android causing the problem. Rather than waste any of your time, I guess I'll have to go with my alternative and just place the checked box in the text area above the Text box. I did learn a few things and I have a much better set of code to work with. (Although I'll be going back to   your first interpretation. Thanks ezanker! Thanks to Omar, also.